# Marketing Cloud Report Not Sendable

Tags: marketing-cloud, send-email

When the user chooses the Audience in Exact Target and tries to select a Salesforce report to pull, the report is shown as **not sendable**. Hence the user is not able to pull the Salesforce report although he/she can see it. Is there a specific access that should be given for this purpose ?

Comment: Can you share fields used in your report?  The report must include ContactID and an email type field in order to be sendable (assuming you are sending to a contact record).

Comment: Hi @DavidDevoy, thank you for your response. The id field is indeed added. As an MC and salesforce admin the report is shown as sendable for me in MC. The user is able to see the reports in SF and see it in MC. But it is shown as not sendable for her. Any advice would be highly appreciated

Comment: This is during the send setup screen, correct? Or are you importing a report into the Marketing Cloud? Is there a particular error that is coming up when this user tries to use the report?

Answer (score 2):

We had the same issue and the problem for us was that the user who got "sendable no" didn't have language set to English in their Salesforce login. Hope it helps for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure marketing user is integrated. Please follow below steps.
Login to marketing cloud as admin -> setup -> users -> click on the respective users you have provided -> click "integrate" -> enter the sales cloud username -> save

These steps fixed my issue.